# Joomla in component does not include mootools in jdoc: type=head

Tags: joomla, joomla-template

I have problem with joomla's search component. When I display the component, there are no mootools included in the head, like on standard pages..
Please in which file is defined what is rendered in jhead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Joomla 1.5 you can use this line of code to include the mootools library:

```
JHTML::_('behavior.mootools');
```

You can use this line in your template's index.php file (mootools will be loaded on every page), or in the search component view.